# Password for multiple PDF files

Tags: pdf

We have 500 PDF files and we also have 500 Unique password to be added to the PDF. Is there any tool to automatically add the password to pdf files(Not a single file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at the products by Appligent. If I remember correctly, they actually have a product which does exactly that. Being command line applications, they are quite flexible and fast.

Comment: Thank you. It worked great and to automate it for 500 pdf I've used dataprovider from TestNG.